# Software installation falis

Tags: software-installation

when i am installing a software using software center or terminal ,i got this (given below)error,but installed software are working.help me to solve this,

i tried the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` , but its not working..

```
smbd start/pre-start, process 29704
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript samba-ad-dc, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winbind:
 winbind depends on samba (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-compizconfig (1:0.9.11.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up compizconfig-settings-manager (1:0.9.11.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
 winbind
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Try to purge samba package and its all these dependencies. And install it again.

Comment: how to purge samba package and its all these dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove samba "sudo apt-get autoremove ..."

Before installation
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

and install one more time "sudo apt-get install samba smbclient"